# Proving an inequality with norms

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$, that $\vec{f}(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$, and that there exists a positive real number $c$ such that $$\left\lVert D\vec{f}(\vec{0})\vec{x}\right\rVert\geq c\lVert\vec{x}\rVert\qquad\text{for all $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$}.$$
>   Prove that there exists a positive real number $r$ such that $$\left\lVert\vec{f}(\vec{x})\right\rVert\geq\frac{c}2\lVert\vec{x}\rVert\;\text{whenever}\;\lVert\vec{x}\rVert\leq r.$$

I'm struggling to even begin to approach this problem. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : $f(x) = f(0) + D \vec f(0) \vec x + o(\| \vec x\|)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the derivatve we have $\frac {\|f(x)-Df(0)x\|} {\|x\|} <\frac  c  2$ when $\|x\|$ is sufficiently small. This gives $\|f(x)\| \geq \|Df(0)\|-\frac  c  2 \|x||\geq c\|x||-\frac  c  2 \|x\|=\frac  c  2 \|x||$.